# Can someone show me an example of how to use threadlocals in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, thread-local

Essentially, I'm trying to access the current user in the models.py in one of my apps. I've already read about how you're not supposed to do this and how you're supposed to do this in the views.py, etc. etc. What I'm trying to accomplish only utilizes the Django admin backend, meaning views.py is not used at all.

Which is why I'm turning to threadlocals. I've looked through a number of questions pertaining to this and all I've found is this dead link: http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/CookBookThreadlocalsAndUser

Frankly, I'm stumped and was hoping someone could provide me with some information on how to use threadlocals, including details on what settings I need to add to my settings.py and what files I need to make.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: The cookbook page you link too was removed because it was presenting a terrible way of hacking around that the Django project rather not promote. See https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13207 I suspect that whatever you are trying to do, perhaps threadlocals are not the way still?

Comment: Essentially, I'm just trying to make a simple email alert system. If anyone creates, modifies or deletes an entry in the admin back end, I'll receive an email as to which user did what to which model. I already figured out how to detect the 3 user actions mentioned above in the models.py as well as how to send email templates. The issue is that I need to the current user information to insert into that email template. And like I mentioned before, this is an admin back end, meaning I'm not touching the views.py at all.

Comment: Does the "entry" model have a foreign key reference to User?

Comment: Yes, the entry model has a foreign key reference to the User. There's the line: "user = models.ForeignKey(User)" However, I believe this 'user' field only saves the username of the user that created the entry though. TBH, I'm still a beginner at Django, and if there's another way to accomplish what I'm trying to do, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on comments, if your `Entry` model has a foreign key to `User`, you don't need to use threadlocals in order to get all of the information about a user after an instance of the model is saved or deleted.

The [Signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/signals/) sub-framework will give you the abilities you're looking for. For example, `pre_delete` could be used to send an email out before the object is deleted. `post_save` could be sent after an entry is created or updated.

The signal handler will receive an instance of the object that triggered the signal, and you'll be able to access the user object, including all of it's properties to send your email out. Although only the id of the User is stored in the database, Django will give you access to the complete object through the ForeignKey field.

[EDIT]

To get the object instance in the signal handler, retrieve it from the kwargs passed to the handler:

```
def my_callback(sender, **kwargs):
    instance = kwargs.get('instance')
    # you can now reference instance.user
    # send email code here
```

Comment: Ah, how might I access the User object in the signal handler? At the moment, I connected the signals to certain methods using lines like: 
"post_save.connect(method_name, sender = Entry, dispatch_uid = 'some unique string')" Is there perhaps a kwargs parameter I could refer to in my method_name?

Comment: I've added an example of how to get the object instance.

Comment: Ah, You're a lifesaver! Thank you so much, it worked! One last request, could you perhaps point me toward some documentation as to what parameters are passed to the signal handler? I was thinking of trying to access the name of the of the Entry being saved and the First and Last names of the user. The documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/signals/ doesn't even mention that the User object is passed. Thanks again!

Comment: Actually, I'm not certain that it's documented anywhere. I just did a print statement on `kwargs` to see what was being passed. `instance` in this case would be an Entry, if you've attached the signal handler to that model.

Comment: Ah, okay, guess I'll fiddle around with it a bit then. Thanks again!